# How do you sort a list based on conditions?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, data, sorting, elements

If i have an list that ranges from 1 - 100.
How can i sort elements from the list. For example i want elements that has greatest common divisor 1 with the number 24.

Comment: Are you actually want to sort or just select elements? In latter case:
`Select[Range[100],GCD[#,24]==1&]`
or:
`Select[Range[100], CoprimeQ[#, 24] &]`

Comment: Please make your question title more representative of the problem at hand. Clarity of your explanations will help respondents to help you more effectively. And yes, welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) by the inventor will help you get started. There is also a fast intro for [math](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) students.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)

SortBy[Range[100], -GCD[#, 24] &]

(* {24, 48, 72, 96, 12, 36, 60, 84, 8, 16, 32, 40, 56, 64, 80, 88, 6, \
18, 30, 42, 54, 66, 78, 90, 4, 20, 28, 44, 52, 68, 76, 92, 100, 3, 9, \
15, 21, 27, 33, 39, 45, 51, 57, 63, 69, 75, 81, 87, 93, 99, 2, 10, \
14, 22, 26, 34, 38, 46, 50, 58, 62, 70, 74, 82, 86, 94, 98, 1, 5, 7, \
11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25, 29, 31, 35, 37, 41, 43, 47, 49, 53, 55, 59, \
61, 65, 67, 71, 73, 77, 79, 83, 85, 89, 91, 95, 97} *)

SortBy[{#, GCD[#, 24]} & /@ Range[100], -Last[#] &]

(* {{24, 24}, {48, 24}, {72, 24}, {96, 24}, {12, 12}, {36, 12}, {60, 
  12}, {84, 12}, {8, 8}, {16, 8}, {32, 8}, {40, 8}, {56, 8}, {64, 
  8}, {80, 8}, {88, 8}, {6, 6}, {18, 6}, {30, 6}, {42, 6}, {54, 
  6}, {66, 6}, {78, 6}, {90, 6}, {4, 4}, {20, 4}, {28, 4}, {44, 
  4}, {52, 4}, {68, 4}, {76, 4}, {92, 4}, {100, 4}, {3, 3}, {9, 
  3}, {15, 3}, {21, 3}, {27, 3}, {33, 3}, {39, 3}, {45, 3}, {51, 
  3}, {57, 3}, {63, 3}, {69, 3}, {75, 3}, {81, 3}, {87, 3}, {93, 
  3}, {99, 3}, {2, 2}, {10, 2}, {14, 2}, {22, 2}, {26, 2}, {34, 
  2}, {38, 2}, {46, 2}, {50, 2}, {58, 2}, {62, 2}, {70, 2}, {74, 
  2}, {82, 2}, {86, 2}, {94, 2}, {98, 2}, {1, 1}, {5, 1}, {7, 1}, {11,
   1}, {13, 1}, {17, 1}, {19, 1}, {23, 1}, {25, 1}, {29, 1}, {31, 
  1}, {35, 1}, {37, 1}, {41, 1}, {43, 1}, {47, 1}, {49, 1}, {53, 
  1}, {55, 1}, {59, 1}, {61, 1}, {65, 1}, {67, 1}, {71, 1}, {73, 
  1}, {77, 1}, {79, 1}, {83, 1}, {85, 1}, {89, 1}, {91, 1}, {95, 
  1}, {97, 1}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Have fun:

```
Manipulate[
 (Table[If[
      CoprimeQ[i, target],
       Style[Framed[i], Red, 20],
      Style[i, Lighter@Gray, 20]
      ], {i, 1, 100}] // Partition[#, 10] & // 
   Grid[#, ItemSize -> {3.5, 3.5}, Frame -> All] &),
 {{target, 50, "Coprime with"}, 1, 100, 1},
 ContentSize -> {600, 600}
 ]
```

[image]